# Powershell IF conditional isn't firing in the way I expected. Unsure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am writing a simple script that makes use of 7zip's command-line to extract archives within folders and then delete the original archives.

There is a part of my script that isn't behaving how I would expect it to. I can't get my if statement to trigger correctly. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
if($CurrentRar.Contains(".part1.rar")){

        [void] $RarGroup.Add($CurrentRar)
        # Value of CurrentRar: 
        # Factory_Selection_2.part1.rar

        $CurrentRarBase = $CurrentRar.TrimEnd(".part1.rar")
        # Value: Factory_Selection_2

        for ($j = 1; $j -lt $AllRarfiles.Count; $j++){

            $NextRar = $AllRarfiles[$j].Name
            # Value: Factory_Selection_2.part2.rar

            if($NextRar.Contains("$CurrentRarBase.part$j.rar")){
                Write-Host "Test Hit" -ForegroundColor Green
                # Never fires, and I have no idea why
                # [void] $RarGroup.Add($NextRar)
            }
        }

        $RarGroups.Add($RarGroup)
    }
```

`if($NextRar.Contains("$CurrentRarBase.part$j.rar"))` is the line that I can't get to fire.

If I shorten it to `if($NextRar.Contains("$CurrentRarBase.part"))`, it fires true. But as soon as I add the inline `$j` it always triggers false. I've tried casting `$j` to string but it still doesn't work. Am I missing something stupid?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around a powershell variable?  A powershell variable starts with a dollar sign.  If you want to add "rar" to end of the variable use this : $CurrentRarBase.part +$j + ".rar"

Comment: Seems like you wanted to do `$AllRarfiles.Contains(` instead of `$NextRar.Contains(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be your `for` statement and the fact that an array / list is zero-indexed (means they start with 0).
In your case, the index `0` of `$AllRarfiles` is probably the `part1` and your `for` statement starts with `1`, but the file name of index `1` does not contain `part1` *(`$NextRar.Contains("$CurrentRarBase.part$j.rar"`)*, but `part2` (`$j + 1`).

### As table comparison

| Index / `$j` | Value | Built string for comparison (with Index) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Factory_Selection_2.part**1**.rar | Factory_Selection_2.part**0**.rar |
| 1 | Factory_Selection_2.part**2**.rar | Factory_Selection_2.part**1**.rar |
| 2 | Factory_Selection_2.part**3**.rar | Factory_Selection_2.part**2**.rar |
| 3 | Factory_Selection_2.part**4**.rar | Factory_Selection_2.part**3**.rar |

## Another simpler approach

Since it seems you want to group split RAR files which belong together, you could also use a simpler approach with `Group-Object`

```powershell
# collect and group all RAR files.
$rarGroups = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\somewhere\' -Filter '*.rar' | Group-Object -Property { $_.Name -replace '\.part\d+\.rar$' } 


# do some stuff afterwards
foreach($rarGroup in $rarGroups){
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Processing RAR group: $($rarGroup.Name)"

    foreach($rarFile in $rarGroup.Group) {
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "`tCurrent RAR file: $($rarFile.Name)"
        # do some stuff per file
    }
}
```